# Fixed UL Menu in Fixed Div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Am new to `ASP.NET` and `CSS`.
I Need to Show Fixed Div and fixed menu in header. And Fixed Header Div have bottom border line and its also have another ul in top of bottom ul like this

```
                       Admin

 New                image 1 image 2 image 3 image 4
 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

so I tried Like this

**CSS**

```
 #DivHeader
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 125px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        position:fixed ;
        z-index: 2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #00e5e6;
    }
      #DivShow
    {
        height: 30Px;
        width: 350px;
        position:fixed;
        float:left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 95px;

    }

       #DivRight 
       {   height: 80Px;
           width: 150px;
           position:fixed;
           left: 85%;
           margin-top: 10px;

       }
        #DivShow ul
    {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width :200px;
    display:inline-block ;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1570a6;
    list-style:none;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 129px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    #DivShow li{float:left;position:relative; cursor:pointer;}
        #DivMenuRight 
       {  
           height: 30Px;
           width: 500px;
           position:fixed;
           right:15%;
           margin-top: 95px;
       }

     #DivRight ul {  position:absolute;
                        width :100px; margin-left:5px; }
       #DivShow li{float:left;position:relative; cursor:pointer;}

        #DivRight ul
        {
            height: 100%;
            text-align:center;
            color: #1570a6;
            list-style:none;
            text-decoration:none;
            table-layout:fixed;
            display:table;

        }

       #DivRight li{cursor:pointer; display:table-cell; 
       margin-top:40px; height:20px; float:left;}

       #UlIcon
       {
        height: 100%;
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding-left: 5px;
        text-decoration:none;
       }

        #UlIcon li {float:right; margin-left:25px;  width : 40px; height:100%;}

        img {
         display:inline-block;
         width:40px;
         height:100%;
         cursor:pointer;
        }
```

**ASP.NET**

```
    <div id="DivHeader">
 <div id="DivShow">
         <ul> <li> Show All </li></ul>
       </div>
             <div id="DivRight">
             <ul> <li > Admin </li></ul>
             </div>
              <div id="DivMenuRight">
                     <ul id="UlIcon">
                     <li id="LiLog"> <img src="IMG/New.png" alt="" /></li>
                     <li id="LiDelete"> <img src="IMG/Delete.png" /></li>
                     <li id="LiSave"> <img src="IMG/Save.png" /></li>
                     <li id="LiNew"> <img src="IMG/New.png" /> </li>
                    </ul> 
             </div>
           </div>
```

But bottom border line overlap with images only so how can i get the solution?
What am doing wrong here?

am using `Visual Studio 2008 and CSS 2.1`

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e6LvsLh2/

Comment: do you have working link?

Comment: @AbrahamSankutty Now Check it Sir

Comment: Try ..increase the height of #DivHeader to 155px

Comment: yeah its work it. @AbrahamSankutty. But its a correct way

Comment: @AbrahamSankutty I change my need now look my question